# Why there is no Python Compressed Archive or Binaries?

Tags: python

**Java** offers download [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) as *Compressed Archive* or **NodeJS** offers download [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) as *Binaries* both give us a compressed file for *Linux* and *Windows* that we can just unzipped it and put in a custom directory and set some environment variables and start working

I'm aware that **Python** also have something called *Embedded Zip* for *Windows* and nothing like that for *Linux* as far as I know, and I think this *Embedded Zip* is not something that the user wants to work with that directly it's for embedding in a C++ application, so it's not the same as options that **Java** and **NodeJS** offering

you can find that most of the programming language has this download feature .NET, Go, Java, Deno, PHP, Node, I'm sure there are many others

My question is why is **Python** hasn't an option for downloading as *Compressed Archive*? Is it's due to a technical issue? political reasons? or is it just simply because nobody has thought of doing it?

Comment: Because they don't. "Why doesn't A have what B has?" is usually an unanswerable question. Simply nobody has created such a thing, that's why. There may be technical reasons, there may be political reasons, maybe simply nobody has thought of doing it.

Comment: @deceze you are right in "Why doesn't A have what B has?" when A and B are completely irrelevant topics, in this case, they are programming languages and the ability to download Compressed Archive is common things as you know so I just tried to find out there is a technical issue that Python can't offer this or not and they maybe release such things in future

Comment: That would be something to ask on the Python mailing list, we can't tell you what they or may not be offering in the future.

Comment: You are in luck. Python supports zip files via the `zipimport` module. On most installations, its already part of the path based finder mechanism. Create `foo.zip` containing `bar.py`, then either put it in a existing python path or have PYTHONPATH point to its directory, and `import foo` starts working. Its always been there.

Comment: @deceze - python supports zip files, and if it didn't, you could always extended the import system with new finders and loaders. There is a non-opinion answer to this question so I think it should be reopened.

Comment: @tdelaney I don't think that's what OP is talking about.

Comment: @deceze can I ask what's the **OP**?

Comment: @deceze - if its the download part, that's what a wheel is. Its the normal way to distribute.

Comment: @tdelaney is not the problem that I'm talking about ...

Comment: @tdelaney OP (that's *you* Sina) is asking why there's no "binary" option on https://www.python.org/downloads/ as there is on https://nodejs.org/en/download/.

Comment: @SinaMobasheri "OP" stands for "original poster"... you. Its a convenient way to mention the person writing the question.

Comment: @SinaMobasheri - what problem, then? You can create compressed package distributions, post them on the network, then they can be downloaded by anybody who wants to install them. You can create your own zip and let people put them on their own machines. What's missing?

Comment: If you want a single executable that contains python's executables and your script, there are multiple choices out there like pyinstaller.

Comment: @tdelaney if you look at [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) download page or [Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) download page they have an option for downloading a zip or tar file that you can unzip and start using language itself not a library, but there is no such thing for python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I post questions in the python mailing list and one of the core Python developers *Christian Heimes* answered like this:

> A distributable binary format for CPython is high on our list. Brett Cannon, Nathaniel Smith, and I have been discussion a proposal recently. I landed a bunch of changes in 3.11-dev that are both useful for binary distribution and for Web Assembly builds. Because all work is done in our free time, there is only little progress.

[reference](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2022-January/904979.html)